# How to use IS NULL in a parametrized query (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, parameters, isnull

I got statements like this:

```
SELECT * From Table WHERE Feld IS NULL
SELECT * From Table WHERE Feld IS NOT NULL
```

Now I'm wondering how I could parametrize this query:

```
SELECT * From Table WHERE Feld IS :Value
```

As I cannot pas 'NOT NULL' to a parameter, I think thats not possible at all - but maybe somebody knows a solution for that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this (tested with Firebird 2.5):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (IIF(FIELD IS NULL, 'Y', 'N') = :IS_NULL)
```

then pass `'Y'` or `'N'` to the `IS_NULL` parameter.

Depending on the database you're using, you might need to replace `IIF` with a `CASE` or similar construct.

Comment: Depending on the OP task, in Firebird may be used [SQL_NULL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-sqlnull.html) data type. But is it supported or not, depends on the data access library, the OP is using.

Comment: @da-soft Interesting link, thank you! But what I understood from that page was that `SQL_NULL` could be used to specify optional parameters, not NULL-ness of queried data. It doesn't seem to be useful for this task.

Comment: It may be useful. For example, if `field` is INTEGER and all values are greater than 0, then the condition may be written: `FIELD > :p OR :p IS NULL AND FIELD IS NULL`. So, when :p=0 then equivalent to `IS NOT NULL`, when :p=NULL then quivalent to `IS NULL`. But again, it depends on the data access library, which supports or not supports SQL_NULL features.

Comment: Want to add - this will work even without SQL_NULL support, but SQL_NULL support makes it more effective.